# Dojo javascript inside floating pane doesn't work well twice

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I am trying to load a registration form inside a dojo floating pane. The form is inside a div which gets loaded via an url

```
http://mysite/register
```

and contains the form body and a javascript file that has some custom validation logic. so it is

```
<div>
   <form>
   </form>
   <script>
   </script>
</div>
```

my script contains for now

```
require(["dojo/parser",
        "dijit/form/Form",
        "dijit/form/Button",
        "dijit/form/ValidationTextBox",
        "ssapp/widgets/AjaxValidationTextBox",
        "dijit/form/DateTextBox",
        "dojox/validate/web",
        "dojox/form/PasswordValidator",
        "dijit/form/FilteringSelect",
        "dijit/form/Select",
        "dijit/form/CheckBox",
        "dojox/layout/TableContainer",
        "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
        "dojo/dom",
        "dojo/query",
        "dojo/_base/xhr",
        "dojo/dom-attr",
        "dojox/validate",
        "dojo/on",
        "dojo/dom-style",
        "dijit/registry",
        "dojo/request",
        "dojo/json",
        "dojo/ready"

    ], function (parser, Form, Button, ValidationTextBox, AjaxValidationTextBox, DateTextBox, web, PasswordValidator, FilteringSelect, Select, CheckBox, TableContainer, ContentPane, dom, query, xhr, domAttr, validate, on, domStyle, registry, request, json, ready) {

        ready(function () {

            console.log('before country select');
            var countrySelect = dijit.byId("id_country"); //keep a reference to country select
            console.log(countrySelect);
        }); });
```

I have a FilteringSelect with a list of all available countries. The first time I open the Floating pane the form is rendered and I get in chrome console

```
before country select 
Object {_attachPoints: Array[4], _attachEvents: Array[0], constraints: Object, baseClass: "dijitTextBox dijitComboBox dijitValidationTextBox", query: Object…}
```

when I close the floating pane I see that the DOM node is removed completely. When I open it again the form renders again but in console I get

```
before country select
undefined
```

It is like it can't find the #id_country or like the script runs before that  has completed loading.

I guess it is beacause the main page has been already loaded and now the document is considered ready. How can I prevent this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems it was a case of timing error. The first time the FloatingPane was loaded there was nothing to be parsed and the required modules were not loaded. So there was plenty of time to load the classes, parse the content and then run the script.

On close the whole DOM tree for the window is deleted.

The second time the classes were already loaded but the dom nodes were not ready. They had to be loaded again from the server and then parsed. But the required classes were already loaded so the script didn't have anything else to do so it proceeded with it's functions. The dijits were not yet ready so the call  `var countrySelect = dijit.byId("id_country");` couldn't find that dijit.

The solution was to wrap the whole script logic inside

```
     dijit.byId('signup-window').on('load', function () {
//script logic here
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the original dijit "id_country" wasn't fully deleted?  So when the page is loaded again, that ID is in use, and it generates a new ID?

If you think the code is running before the page is fully loaded (seems unlikely) try running that code in a timeout, so you can be sure the page is finished loading.